# http-proxy-middleware adding custom header

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I'm using `http-proxy-middleware` to setup request proxy from auth service to secured API.

Here I need to add custom header with authenticated user auth ID for every incoming request to the authentication layer. But with following implementation header not adding to the request. Here I've used **on.proxyReq**,

```js
app.use('/info', auth, createProxyMiddleware({
    target: process.env.BASE_API_URL,
    changeOrigin: false,
    on: {
        proxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
            console.log(`On Proxy Request ${proxyReq}`);
            proxyReq.setHeader('x-auth-user', 'b05ff410-fbba-11ec-bfce-ddefb9f79237');
        },
        proxyRes: (proxyRes, req, res) => {
            console.log(`On Proxy Response ${proxyRes}`);
        },
        error: (err, req, res) => {
            console.log(`On Error Request ${err}`);
        },
    },
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has resolved with following,

```js
app.use('/info', auth, createProxyMiddleware({
    target: process.env.BASE_API_URL,
    changeOrigin: false,
    onError: (err, req, res, target) => {
        res.writeHead(500, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });
        res.end({ message: 'Something went wrong on proxy request. Please retry.' });
    },
    onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
        proxyReq.setHeader('x_auth_user', req.user.email);
    }
}));
```